# Matlab: Find the most repeated value in a cell (revised)

Tags: matlab, mode, cell-array

To my code   idxcell{:,1} for 1:10 iterations gives the following results:

```
ans =
         9    10    14    15    19    20    24    25
    ans =
      Columns 1 through 13
         7     8    11    12    13    14    16    17    18    19    21    22    23
      Column 14
        24
    ans =
        13    14    15    18    19    20    23    24    25
    ans =
         6     7    11    12    16    17    21    22
    ans =
        16    17    21    22
    ans =
         6     7    11    12    13    16    17    21
    ans =
         4     5     8     9    10    13    14    15    19    20
    ans =
         4     5     8     9    10    14    15
    ans =
        11    12    13    14    16    17    18    19    21    22    23    24
    ans =
         1     2     3     6     7     8    11    12    13
```

How can i get the most repeated value of those cell's elements (i think on that paradigm is the '14')? I dont want index of it only the value.
I have tried

```
idxcell{:,1}
temp = idxcell{:,1};
M = mode(temp)
```

but got result for first cell only and i am not sure that mode() is what i have to use for my purpose.

---

**This was answered by [angainor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644189/angainor):** `mode([idxcell{:}])`

---

**Revised:** Also is it possible to search for all cell arrays/rows in once for i iterations to find the most repeated value and sort the results, most repeated to less, inside a cell array or matrix in descending order?

---

|Answered by me after [angainor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644189/angainor) tip: `Sort = sort([idxcell{:}])`

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to concatenate all the cell vectors into one before you call `mode`

```
mode([idxcell{:}])
ans =

13
```

If you want to get the most frequently appearing value for all cells, you can use `cellfun`

```
cellfun(@mode, idxcell)
ans =

 9    10    14    15    19    20    24    25
```

Comment: Fast and spot on answer. Be well.

Comment: `cellfun(@mode, idxcell)` return value is only for the first cell row. @angainor Is it possible to add all cell rows/arrays to a matrix and search inside this matrix for the most repeated value? and if yes how can be done?

Comment: @professor this call returns a matrix, in which the elements are the result of calling the `mode` function for **every cell element**. I don't really understand what you mean by 'first cell row'. If your cell array is of size `(n,m)`, this call returns a `(n,m)` matrix.

Comment: sorry revised my question asking for a total of i iterations if those cells arrays can be sorted in one cellmatrix and execute the `cellfun(@mode, cellmatrixidxcell)` for it. @angainor

Comment: @professor why don't you run `sort` on the results of `cellfun`?

Comment: Done that `Sort = sort([idxcell{:}])`. Thanks for the tip haven't thought that. Be well @angainor.